How to get JVM GC pause time metrics?
Is there any way to get JVM GC pause time metrics in the prometheus format using JMX exporter or any other way?
I have used JMX exporter and tried to export the metrics using the following mbean
java.lang:name=G1 Young Generation,type=GarbageCollector
But that one only gives the collection count and total collection time metrics. Not the GC Pause time metrics.

You might be able to configure JFR to get pause times and then send that to prometheus.

Yeah we know that we can get this from JFR or from the log but we are preferring to get this in the metrics form using the JMX mbean or JMX exporter. Thanks

If you get a com.sun.management.GarbageCollectorMXBean, you might be able to obtain the GcInfo which can also contain GC specific attributes. I think this would be equivalent to com.sun.management:type=GarbageCollector or something like that (I don't know much about JMX).

Yeah this one is the GarbageCollector mbean that I was trying to use. It only exposes collection time and collection counts. Not Safepoints sync time, gc pause time etc.

Are you using the one from com.sun.management or the one from java.lang.management? I think only the former has GcInfo.

Oh yeah I have used the java.lang one not com.sun.management. Have to see if JMX also exposes the com.sun.management one or not
